# Cannot find what the PCB reference designator "CE" refers to

Tags: components

I'm trying to figure out what parts are being used on a board. There are various PCB reference designators that are stumping me and I'm having trouble figuring out what the components are. In this instance, the reference designator "CE" is being used. Is this a electrolytic capacitor?  Any help would be appreciated!

[image: CE2 component]

Comment: It looks like an electrolytic capacitor (Polarized footprint, relatively tall package).

Comment: I vote for Capacitor-Electrolytic. If it were an inductor it would measure zero ohms across it with a meter. Diodes aren't usually marked with a + sign.

Comment: Is this a French device? It might be capaciteur electrolytique, and the designations being French abbreviations might account for the "various PCB reference designators that are stumping me" as well.

Comment: A larger view of the PCB will also let people suggest with more confidence.

Comment: @Guntram Blohm: for a French electronician, this is a "Condensateur Électrolytique".

Comment: A positive terminal is usually marked on a capacitor. I am not aware of any other two terminal component (besides diode) that would have terminal marked like this. Diodes are not marked with a + on a terminal, only capacitors are.

Comment: @fgrieu-onstrike Ohhh, that explains why I've seen people say "condensator" when they meant capacitor--they were probably French.

Comment: @quantum231 Most capacitors mark the negative terminal; it's only tantalums that mark the positive.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a [Panasonic TPE-Series Tantalum capacitor](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/AAA8000/AAA8000C36.pdf) (220uF, 6.3V).

[image]

Comment: It says "Conductive Polymer Tantalum"; this implies that there are infact, multiple different types of Tantalum capacitors as well?

Answer (score 11):

The device there is very obviously a tantalum electrolytic (the only common device that I'm aware of that usually has its positive terminal marked, and tantalums usually come in packages like that too), so I'm going to agree with td127 in the comments and say it probably stands for "Capacitor, Electrolytic".

Answer (score -8):

This doesn't look like a capacitor to me, it is more of inductor or diode. Reference designators can be misleading because its manual referance designator it depends on what the designer had in his mind while doing this layout. Maybe it is a placeholder for a diode or a capacitor. Maybe it is a mistake he realized later and he instructed CM to install a diode on a capacitor foot print.

Comment: Try and save the answer section for definitive answers. "Maybe this, maybe that" doesn't make for a good answer.